# JS Ajax div css style is not updating

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, jsp, servlets

I want to show the last position of the circle div to be refreshed on each time I change the location of the position of the circle from one web page

(one user is changing the position and others should be able to view the changed position without refreshing their web browser)

currently other users have to refresh their web browser to get the latest position of the circle.

```
<%@page import="bo.Circle"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="org.w3c.dom.Document"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Arrow key movements</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var moveDiv = document.getElementById("movingDiv");
        window.onkeydown = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (!e) {
                e = window.event;
            }
            var keyCode;

            var speed = 3;
            if (e.which) {
                keyCode = e.which;
            } else {
                keyCode = e.keyCode;
            }

            if (keyCode === 37) {
                moveDiv.style.left = (parseInt(moveDiv.style.left, 10) - speed)
                        + 'px';
                sendRequest();
            } else if (keyCode === 38) {
                moveDiv.style.top = (parseInt(moveDiv.style.top, 10) - speed)
                        + 'px';
                sendRequest();
            } else if (keyCode === 39) {
                moveDiv.style.left = (parseInt(moveDiv.style.left, 10) + speed)
                        + 'px';
                sendRequest();
            } else if (keyCode === 40) {
                moveDiv.style.top = (parseInt(moveDiv.style.top, 10) + speed)
                        + 'px';
                sendRequest();
            }
        };
    };
    function createXMLHttpRequest() {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        return xmlhttp;
    }
    function sendRequest() {

        var circle = document.getElementById('movingDiv');
        var textCircle = circle.getBoundingClientRect();
        var top = textCircle.top;
        var right = textCircle.right;
        var bottom = textCircle.bottom;
        var left = textCircle.left;

        var url = "MyServlet?right=" + right + "&bottom=" + bottom + "&left="
                + left + "&top=" + top;

        var request = createXMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", url, true);
        request.send(null);

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
                if (request.status == 200) {
                    var output = request.responseText;
                    var res = output.split(":");
                    var top = res[0];
                    var left = res[1];
                    var moveDiv = document.getElementById("movingDiv");

                    //here I set styles of div styles to be refreshed in other users of page
                    document.getElementById('movingDiv').style.top = top + 'px';
                    document.getElementById('movingDiv').style.left = left
                            + 'px';
                    ;

                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<!-- CSS fpr moving Div -->
<style type="text/css">
#movingDiv {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    border: 3px solid red;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <%
        ArrayList<Circle> circleList = (ArrayList<Circle>) application.getAttribute("list");
        Circle circle = null;
        int bottom = 0;
        int left = 0;
        int right = 0;
        int top = 0;
        if (circleList != null) {
            for (Circle circle2 : circleList) {
                circle = circle2;
            }

            left = (int) Math.round(Double.parseDouble(circle.getLeft()));
            top = (int) Math.round(Double.parseDouble(circle.getTop()));
        }
    %>

    <div id="movingDiv" style="top: <%=top%>px; left: <%=left%>px;"
        onkeypress="sendRequest();"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the Servlet which handles the above jsp
servlet side is okay as I think as it returns latest position of the circle to the jsp I have checked the returning text of servlet by using a alert

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String top = request.getParameter("top");
        String right = request.getParameter("right");
        String bottom = request.getParameter("bottom");
        String left = request.getParameter("left");

        ServletContext ctx = getServletContext();

        // HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        // String id = session.getId();
        // if(session.isNew()){

        ArrayList<Circle> circleList = (ArrayList<Circle>) ctx.getAttribute("list");
        if (circleList == null) {
            circleList = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        Circle myCircle = new Circle(top, right, bottom, left);
        circleList.add(myCircle);

        ctx.setAttribute("list", circleList);
        // }

        try {
            out.print(top + ":" + left);
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }
}
```

I want to refresh the div styles of #movingDiv(top and left positions).
although the latest positions values returned to jsp it does not update the postion.

Live version of this project available on - http://128.199.104.22:8080/MyAjax/

eclipse project can be downloaded here  - http://128.199.104.22/MyAjax.rar

Thank you very much!